# executing jenkins job based on svn update?

Tags: ant, jenkins

I am creatig a new Jenkin Job. This job is using SVN version control and coding is done in Java and also i am creating jar using ANT.

Now I would like to create job that detects changes in svn repository. 
i.e., When ever the developer changes the code jenkins job need to executed automatically.

Can any one please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you given [Subversion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin) a read?

Post-commit hook is of concern to you -

Jenkins can poll Subversion repositories for changes, and while this is reasonably efficient, this can only happen up to every once a minute, so you may still have to wait a full minute before Jenkins detects a change.

To reduce this delay, you can set up a [post commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) so the Subversion repository can notify Jenkins whenever a change is made to that repository.